# Absolute content is overflowing beyond the relative parent

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with `position:absolute` and a child div with content. Yet when I add too much text into the child div, it overflows in the parent div. The container div of the parent has `position:relative`.

If anybody can help me with this issue, I'd appreciate it.

What I don't want is an `overflow:scroll`. I want the container to grow, in height, with the child.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hs4o003o/)

```css
    #main{
     float:left;
     width:100%;
     padding:75px 0 55px 0;
        background-color:#999;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    .contentpage img{
     display:block;
     margin-bottom:40px;
    }
    
    #leftsection{
     width:50%;
     float:left;
    }
    
    #leftcontent{
     width:480px;
     float:right;
    }
    
    #leftcontent img{
     background:red;
        height:453px;
        width:453px;
    }
    
    #rightsection{
     width: -moz-calc(50% - 150px);
        width: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
        width: calc(50% - 150px);
     margin:-75px 0 0 150px;
     padding-bottom:20px;
     height:100%;
     float:left;
     background-color:#f3f5f7;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
    
    #rightsection > #rightcontent{
     padding:85px 0 20px 35px;
     max-width:330px;
    }
    
    #rightcontent{
     width:auto;
     float:left;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="main" class="contentpage">
        <div id="leftsection">
            <div id="leftcontent">
                <div id="breadcrumbs">Bread / crumbs</div>
       <img src="images/afbeelding1.png"/>
       <img src="images/afbeelding2.png"/>
      </div>
     </div>
        <div id="rightsection">
      <div id="rightcontent">
       <h1>Title</h1>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
         
       <h2>Things:</h2>
       <ul>
           <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
       </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hs4o003o/2/) what you want?

Comment: @Abhi No, sorry. I forgot to be more clear in my question. I don't want a scrollbar. I want the container to grow with the child div, in height.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `height:100%;` of div with position:absolute;. It means 100% of display height. It will be better if you remove `position:absolute;` http://jsfiddle.net/hs4o003o/6/

Comment: That's not an option. If I were to display less text in the #rightsection, the div wouldn't have a height of 100%. That's why it has position:absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height:100%` on `#rightsection` div.

```
#rightsection{
    width: -moz-calc(50% - 150px);
    width: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
    width: calc(50% - 150px);
    margin:-75px 0 0 150px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    /*height:100%;*/
    float:left;
    background-color:#f3f5f7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not an option. If I were to display less text in the `#rightsection`, the div wouldn't have a height of 100%. That's why it has `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the properties absolute for relative. make the child element relative and the parent element absolute. Then it will grow with the child.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hs4o003o/7/)

```
 #main{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:75px 0 55px 0;
    background-color:#999;
    position: relative;
}

#rightsection{
    width: -moz-calc(50% - 150px);
    width: -webkit-calc(50% - 150px);
    width: calc(50% - 150px);
    margin:-75px 0 0 150px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#f3f5f7;
    position: relative;

}
```

Here is another [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/hs4o003o/8/) of the child being relative as well.

Finally I think this may be the solution you are looking for. I think if you are using the same div id #main elsewher it could cause you trouble but here is the [DEMO3](http://jsfiddle.net/hs4o003o/10/)

Comment: Adding `position:absolute` to the #main ruins the entire format.

Comment: `#main` is used by multple pages. If positioning doesn't work. I'm forced to look for another way.

Comment: Well my bad but you could also set the child position to relative and the parent will grow with it.

Comment: but then the `#rightsection` won't grow max height should there be less text.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. #rightsection will remain the size of its contents. In this case the text inside of it.

Comment: I don't want the `#rightsection` to have the size of the contents, but the size of the parent. Should there be more content, the `#rightsection` grows but should there be less, it should expand to the size of the parent.

Comment: Can you tell me if DEMO3 is what you are looking for?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's not. When I remove a lot of text you can see `#rightsection` shrinking. I think I may have to get Javascript involved. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't say how to handle the overflow, so I updated your fiddle to work with `scroll`: http://jsfiddle.net/hs4o003o/1/

Also, since you said "text", I had to assume you were talking about `#rightcontent`, right?

I simply added two lines of CSS to `#rightsection > #rightcontent`:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
max-height: 100%;
```

The first one should speak for itself and the second one is necessary to tell the browser from what point on the `overflow-y` property should take effect.